# no puedo restaurar una base de datos en postgressql

Tags: postgresql

intento restaurar una base de datos y me dice que el proceso falló. También intenté hacer un backup de una BD y también me da error. Pienso que puede ser algo de permisos pero no encue[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]ntro qué puede ser

Comment: Pon el mensaje del error

Comment: como código de error me sale "Failed (exit code: 3221225781)"

Comment: [¿Mismo caso?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77462578)